# git on command line no longer works on El Capitan

Tags: bash, git, xcode

Having just installed OS X 10.11 last night, I was surprised to see that my Bash terminal did the following:

```
$ git
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
```

Previous version of XCode did not transfer to the new OS. I tried a fresh install of Git, but still had the same XCode failure in Bash.

Is there  good reason for this?

Comment: When that command-line message happens, you should also see a GUI dialog offering to install the latest version of the Xcode command-line tools. Did that not happen?

Comment: Yeah once I installed XCode it worked... I was more wondering why git now has a dependency on the Apple Dev Tools...?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For me, this was a solution:

```
xcode-select --install
```

After the installation, git started to work again.

Comment: Good call thanks. Will mark as correct although I installed XCode and this fixed it too.

Comment: Thanks :) This is my first answer on StackExchange, so it will help me to earn reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Faced this after upgrading to El-Capitan

```
xcode-select --install
```

didn't work for me even after 'Finding Software' and Downloading. I don't have Xcode.app installed (Didn't want to install it) so i fixed it by downloading [Command Line Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjS3f.png) from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ (requires Apple SignIn) and installed it manually.

After installation i was able to run `git` commands again

Comment: I believe that the command `xcode-select --install` does exactly the same thing - install the Command Line Tools. You can read this in the command's help: `xcode-select --help`. I think it does not require Xcode.app to be installed.